# Updating value inside nested object of object in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

I have state set as follow

```
const [stories, setStories] = useState([]);
```

I fetch Data from API in array, and i map the array and set the using setStories as:

```
setStories(prevState => prevState.concat({user: {name: 'XYZ', profile: 'ABC', stories: [{id: 1, image: 'testing'}];
```

The above codes are working fine, but i am stuck, when i have to concat the latest story if the id did not matched with fetched data. I have tried below solution but it didnot help:

```
stories.map(story => {
if(story && story.hasOwnProperty(key)){
//where above key is the user key fetched from the another API, i.e., user key
story?.[key].stories.map(storedStory => 
id(storedStory.id !== fetchedStory.id){
story?.[key].stories.concat({story})}
```

but the above code did not work, as it only mutate the state and is avoiding re-rendering.
Looking for a clean and efficient method to overcome this. THanks

Comment: Shouldn't you set the story using `setStories` for the last line?

Comment: Tried it already, it just throw the error and change the order of object and mutate the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish without seeing a full example. But I think your main problem is that you're not using the returned value from `map`, and from the naming it looks like you're appending the wrong element.

It will help to simplify first.

```
  const newState = stories.map(story => {
    if (story?.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const found = story[key].stories.find(s => s.id === fetchedStory.id);

      if (found) {
        return story;
      } else {
        // Let's make a new object with the fetchedStory
        // appended into THIS user's stories
        return {
          ...story,
          [key]: {
            ...story[key],
            stories: [
              ...story[key].stories,
              // This is supposed to be fetchedStory
              // not `story` right??
              fetchedStory,
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      return story;
    }
  });

  setStory(newState);
```

Edit: You're having a hard time expressing your business logic, and the complexity of the data structure is not helping. So keep simplifying, encapsulate the complex syntax into functions then express your business logic plainly. Ie,

```
const appendStory = (originalObject, userId, storyToAppend) => {
  return {
    ...originalObject,
    [userId]: {
      ...originalObject[userId],
      stories: [
        ...originalObject[userId].stories,
        storyToAppend,
      ]
    }
  }
};

const userExistsInList = (users, user) => {
  return users?.hasOwnProperty(user);
}

const newStoryAlreadyInStories = (stories, newStory) => {
  return stories.find(s => s.id === newStory.id);
}

const newState = stories.map(story => {
  if (userExistsInList(story, key)) {
    
    const found = newStoryAlreadyInStories(story[key].stories, fetchedStory);

    if (found) {
      // User is already in state and the new story is already in the list
      // Add business logic here
    } else {
      // User is already in state and the new story
      // is not in their list
      // Add business logic here
    }
  } else {
    // User is not in the list yet
    // Add business logic here
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working however there is a minor issue with this solution, let suppose i am getting the stories array from my server and mapping it; and applying your solution and as react does not allow mutability, so if there are two object in story array, and i am, when a story already available in the story array it simply return the user (as above) which only contain the previous or the old story.... any solution for this?

Comment: The above `else` block creates a new object with `fetchedStory` appended to the existing list of `stories`. If you want that in all cases, then remove the `if (found) return story`.

Comment: Tried else statement with if(!found), and getting nothing or empty stories if stories found

Comment: and also using the only else block with if(!found) is making the state undefined, if there is a story found

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, what i am doing is getting the firestore result and looping through the result with array.map and implementing the above business logic, but as the useState is asynchronous, so i fail to set the state. for the second time